# Investigation in Buenos Aires, Argentina

Tags: website, argentina

I am trying to investigate a relative that migrated to Argentina. I have been able to find the references to the records of marriage and death.

What I know:

Name: Pedro Peñalba Águeda
Marriage: 16/12/1943 at Buenos Aires on book 253 and page 34
Death: 20/03/1980 at Buenos Aires on book 198 and page 356

It is not clear if the records belong to Buenos Aires city or the province of Buenos Aires.

Is anybody able to support in trying to identify further information or to access to the records online?
(FamilySearch did not give me any info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it says "Buenos Aires" it refers to the city of Buenos Aires and not to the province. You could ask for the birth certificate directly at the civil registry of the city.
Here is the [link](https://www.buenosaires.gob.ar/tramites/solicitud-de-partidas).